# This site can’t be reached for aws s3 and cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I uploaded a static html site to s3 following this guideline: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037983412-Configuring-an-Amazon-Web-Services-static-site-to-use-Cloudflare

**On s3 I created 2 bucket:**

1. Root domain bucket: test1014.xyz (just a redirect to subdomain)
2. Subdomain bucket: www.test1014.xyz (contains the html file)

For the subdomain bucket, I blocked all public access and added a permission for cloudflare:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.test1014.xyz/*",
        "Condition": {
            "NotIpAddress": {
                "aws:SourceIp": [
                    "173.245.48.0/20",
                    "103.21.244.0/22",
                    "103.22.200.0/22",
                    "103.31.4.0/22",
                    "141.101.64.0/18",
                    "108.162.192.0/18",
                    "190.93.240.0/20",
                    "188.114.96.0/20",
                    "197.234.240.0/22",
                    "198.41.128.0/17",
                    "162.158.0.0/15",
                    "104.16.0.0/13",
                    "104.24.0.0/14",
                    "172.64.0.0/13",
                    "131.0.72.0/22",
                    "2400:cb00::/32",
                    "2606:4700::/32",
                    "2803:f800::/32",
                    "2405:b500::/32",
                    "2405:8100::/32",
                    "2a06:98c0::/29",
                    "2c0f:f248::/32"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

**On **cloudflare** I added 2 domains:**

1. CNAME | test1014.xyz | test1014.xyz.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
2. CNAME | www | www.test1014.xyz.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

[image]

Basically I just followed the guideline and still keep getting "**This site can’t be reached** ".
I already updated my domain nameserver to cloudflare.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 content is private by default.

The policy you show is a `Deny` policy. It is normally used **in addition to an `Allow` policy** to override the settings.

Therefore, you should either add an "Allow All" policy as well, or modify the `Deny` policy to be an `Allow` policy that grants access only if access via those IP addresses.

By the way, `Deny` policies are very difficult to get right. For example, it would also mean that YOU cannot access an object in S3 (eg to download a file) unless you do it via CloudFlare. They are best avoided if possible.

**Update:** Here's a bucket policy that only permits access (theoretically) to CloudFlare. It avoids using a `Deny` policy.

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::www.test1014.xyz/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "173.245.48.0/20",
                        "103.21.244.0/22",
                        "103.22.200.0/22",
                        "103.31.4.0/22",
                        "141.101.64.0/18",
                        "108.162.192.0/18",
                        "190.93.240.0/20",
                        "188.114.96.0/20",
                        "197.234.240.0/22",
                        "198.41.128.0/17",
                        "162.158.0.0/15",
                        "104.16.0.0/13",
                        "104.24.0.0/14",
                        "172.64.0.0/13",
                        "131.0.72.0/22",
                        "2400:cb00::/32",
                        "2606:4700::/32",
                        "2803:f800::/32",
                        "2405:b500::/32",
                        "2405:8100::/32",
                        "2a06:98c0::/29",
                        "2c0f:f248::/32"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I changed the policy to allow all and enable public access all but still getting the same error, u can visit here: http://www.test1014.xyz.s3-website-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/ but the dns is not working

Comment: When I go there, it says "This is a test!". I don't know if that's the result you wanted.

Comment: yes, thats the website

Comment: I have added a suggested policy that would grant CloudFlare access to the S3 bucket. If that is the only Bucket Policy, then the bucket will remain private.

Comment: still the same result. but putting aside policy, previously i allowed all access, and u can visit the website. isnt this a cloudflare issue ? cause all i have to do is add a cname to point to the website url

Comment: Let's step back a bit... Do you own the domain name called `test1014.xyz`? The [WHOIS](https://who.is/whois/test1014.xyz) for that domain is pointing to Amazon Route53 nameservers, not CloudFlare. Did you follow Step #2 on [Add a site · Cloudflare Fundamentals docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/fundamentals/get-started/setup/add-site/)?